# Cypress: Is it possible to extract a URL of a new browser tab that will be opened by a click?

Tags: cypress

I need to extract a URL of a new browser tab that will be opened by a double click on an element. Element is not a link so there is no any "href" attr. Once we dblclick on this item, we will have a proper url that I need to extract (and parse further).

```
    cy.visit("Runtime/Runtime/Form/Home/");
    cy.contains("item").should('be.visible').dblclick(); 
    const url = // to do
```

I know that cypress does not support multiple tabs testing but I don't need to do any testing on a tab...just what to get that url. Is it possible?

Comment: can you post the HTML DOM of the element that has the URL ?

Comment: I'm not sure that cypress has access to address bar of new window if you mean it

Comment: The Window object has an `origin` property that gives you the url. The problem is that there is no reference to the new window in the test. It might be obtained from the app - do you have access to the source code, specifically the `dblclick()` handler?

Answer (score 0):

One way to test that is use Chrome and disable Web security in **cypres.json**:

```
"chromeWebSecurity": false
```

Then you could do:

```
cy.contains("item").should('be.visible').dblclick()
cy.url()
.then((url) => {
  expect(url).to.contain('some-string')
})
```

Comment: Hi Leonardo, once we double click, we will open a new browser tab with a new url that I want to achieve. But if we run your example, we will check the same url as we had before a click was done. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm afraid Cypress does not handle opening other tabs. That is why the URL does not change. Cannot figure out a solution.